# Two patterns in same log file is not working in log4j2

Tags: log4j2

I'd like to configure log4j 2 with two different patterns in same appender. i.e., Whenever there is an error, a specific pattern should be present in the log file. I am not trying two different log files, but two different pattern in same log file. Whenever there is an error, I would see "MYDOMAINDOTCOM_SUPPORT_NEEDED" and this string will trigger an automatic email to support team.

I have the below configuration which prints error message in "RollingFile" appender only and "RollingFileError" appender is ignored. What am I missing ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="DEBUG">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="log-path">/documents/log</Property>
    </Properties>
    <Appenders>
        <RollingFile name="RollingFile" fileName="${log-path}/myexample.log"
            filePattern="${log-path}/$${date:yyyy-MM}/myexample-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log"
            immediateFlush="true">
            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%t] %-5p %c{1}:%L - %X{packetRefId} - %msg%n</pattern>
                <!-- %d{dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS}- %c{1}: %m%n -->
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="100 KB" />
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="4" />
        </RollingFile>
        <RollingFile name="RollingFileError" fileName="${log-path}/myexample.log"
            filePattern="${log-path}/$${date:yyyy-MM}/myexample-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log"
            immediateFlush="true">
            <param name="threshold" value="error" />
            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern>MYDOMAINDOTCOM_SUPPORT_NEEDED %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%t] %-5p %c{1}:%L - %X{packetRefId} - %msg%n</pattern>
                <!-- %d{dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS}- %c{1}: %m%n -->
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="100 KB" />
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="4" />
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="org.springframework.beans.factory" level="info" additivity="false">
          <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
        </Logger>
        <Logger name="root" level="debug" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" level="debug" />
            <appender-ref ref="RollingFileError" level="error" />
        </Logger>
        <Root level="debug" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should never configure two appenders to write to the same file. Having two rolling file appenders that both use the same file and roll over to the same file pattern is never going to work correctly.

Also, your configuration would end up with all error messages being logged twice; once with the RollingFile appender due to its debug level, and once on the RollingFileError appender due to its error level.

Instead, you should have a single rolling file appender and use a PatternSelector to decide which pattern to use. See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html#Pattern_Selectors for documentation on pattern selectors.

Comment: Thank you so much ! I used PatternSelector and it works exactly as I wanted.

Comment: @rgoers: unless I am mistaken, both appenders will share the same `RollingFileManager`, so rolling over will be performed only once. If the user wanted to use two different layouts (e.g. pattern and JSON), I think such a config would be acceptable.