# Java log4j2.xml : Different log patterns for different base packages in same rolling log file

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

I have an application where there are some custom jars added. One of the jars expects logging to be in a different pattern from the entire application's common logging pattern.

(We are using log4j2.xml way)

Now it is pretty straightforward to do it in Console logs by adding multiple appenders, with different patterns and associating  them with the corresponding logger name (base package of the custom jar)

But is there a way to do it in the RollingFile Appenders in the same file ?

Consider the example below

- Base application having base log pattern has Logger name = `com.legacysystem.base`
- Custom jar within the application needing custom log pattern has logger name = `com.legacysystem.custom`
- Log pattern for base and custom jar is defined in properties with variable names `log-pattern` and `log-pattern`
- please ignore the fact that proper pattern value is not added, as i want to keep it hidden (assume log4j2-pattern.xml is present with proper log format)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN" xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude">
    <xi:include href="log4j2-pattern.xml">
        <xi:fallback >
            <Properties>
                <Property name="log-pattern">base_log_pattern</Property>
                <Property name="custom-log-pattern">custom_log_pattern</Property>

            </Properties>
        </xi:fallback>
    </xi:include>
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="ConsoleBaseAppender">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${log-pattern}"/>
        </Console>

        <Console name="ConsoleCustomAppender">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${custom-log-pattern}"/>
        </Console>

        <RollingFile name="FILE" fileName="commonFileName.log" filePattern="commonFileName-%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH}-%i.log.gz">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${log-pattern}"/>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy/>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="25MB"/>
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="20"/>
        </RollingFile>

       <RollingFile name="CUSTOM_FILE" fileName="commonFileName.log" filePattern="commonFileName-%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH}-%i.log.gz">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${custom-log-pattern}"/>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy/>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="25MB"/>
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="20"/>
        </RollingFile>

    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name = "com.legacysystem.custom" level="INFO" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="CUSTOM_FILE" />
            <AppenderRef ref="ConsoleCustomAppender" />
        </Logger>


        <Logger name="com.legacysystem.base" level="INFO" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="FILE" />
            <AppenderRef ref="ConsoleBaseAppender" />
        </Logger>

        <Root level="INFO">
            <AppenderRef ref="FILE" />
            <AppenderRef ref="ConsoleBaseAppender" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

In the above example, I have succeeded in getting different log patterns in the console, but log files isn't working.
Also, is there a better way to do it without defining two rolling file appenders pointing to same file name ?

Comment: Why would a custom jar expect logging to be in a different format? Is it parsing the logfiles?

Comment: custom jar has json log pattern which is used for some metrics collection for dashboards that expects json based pattern

Comment: the above xml seems to be working with multiple Rolling file appenders. However it is not recommended 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36212857/two-patterns-in-same-log-file-is-not-working-in-log4j2

Comment: I don't see how a custom jar can hjave a different log pattern. The log pattern is what you define in your application, it isn't enforced by a jar.

Comment: Pattern is enforced by the application, which is the base pattern. But with that, the logs published by the custom jar's code is broken. So I am trying to enforce log pattern for the custom package to follow custom log pattern and remaining app to follow base pattern

Comment: Just like we can have different log patterns for different log levels, I am trying to figure out if it is possible to have different log patterns for different Logger packages.